# Having a closure issue. Can't seem to resolve it. Please advise

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have this code:

```
  _trackit: function(){
  for(var key in this.items.sublinks){
     switch(key){
         case 'shoes':
            for(var innerkey in this.items.sublinks[key]){
                (function(){
                  $(innerkey).observe('click', (function(e){
                    Event.stop(e);
                    someClass.click_link( this.items.sublinks[key][innerkey],false)
                   }));
                 )(this);
            }  
         break;
     }
  }
 }
```

The hash I am passing in has a size of 2. But as you would guess both of the links (since the hash maps to links), are passing the last hash value to come through (`someClass.click_link` <- in here this value, `this.item.sublinks[key][innerkey]`).

I've tried using an innerfuction etc... but something is messing up. If I go to "inner function deep", then `this.items` returns `undefined`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, you need to have an argument to receive the "this" you are passing. You will also need to pass copies of the "key" and "innerkey" variables, in order to avoid the closures inside for loops bug.

```
var make_event_listener = function(that, key, innerKey){
    return function(e){
        Event.stop(e);
        someClass.click_link( that.items.sublinks[key][innerkey], false)
    };
};

//...
for(var innerkey in this.items.sublinks[key]){
   $(innerkey).observe('click', make_event_listener(this, key, innerKey) );
}
//...
```

OF course, you can use an anonymous version of make_event_listener instead but I find this way more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're passing `this` in as an argument, you just need to create a parameter for it — call it, say, `_this` — and then you can refer to `_this` instead of `this` inside the function:

```
                (function(_this, innerkey){
                  $(innerkey).observe('click', (function(e){
                    Event.stop(e);
                    someClass.click_link( _this.items.sublinks[key][innerkey],false)
                   }));
                 )(this, innerkey);
```

(There are other ways as well, but the above seems to be the way you were going for when you passed `this` in as an argument? And it's a perfectly respectable way to do it.)

**Edited to add:** Per Rob W's comment, I've edited the above to add `innerkey` as a parameter as well, since otherwise the inner `function(e){...}` expression will refer to the same `innerkey` *variable* as the outer function — a variable which, as a loop variable, is likely to have changed by the time the inner function actually runs. Passing it as a parameter gives the inner expression a new `innerkey` variable that's equal to what `innerkey` *was* when the inner function was created.

Comment: Don't forget about the `innerKey` variable.

Comment: @RobW: Right, it can have changed what it refers to by the time the closure is actually run. Good point, I'll fix that; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The second call to "this" references the actual element being clicked. Change it to:

```
_trackit: function () {
    var self = this;
    for (var key in this.items.sublinks) {
        switch (key) {
        case 'shoes':
            for (var innerkey in this.items.sublinks[key]) {
                (function () {
                    $(innerkey).observe('click', (function (e) {
                        Event.stop(e);
                        someClass.click_link(self.items.sublinks[key][innerkey], false)
                    }));)(this);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```